# Probability that station select a different radio frequencies

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Question: Two synchronous stations use frequency-hopping to select at random (with probability 1/n one of n frequencies. What is the probability that the stations select a different frequency?

My approach to solving this would be that the probability to select same frequency would be 1/n, so it for the probability of selecting a different frequency would be 1 - 1/n

Is my understanding correct? Or would it be n/(nC2) for same frequency?

Comment: It would be $1 - \frac{1}{n}$. For any given frequency, both of them having the same would be $\frac{1}{n^2}$ and there are $n$ frequencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, correct.

The probability that the 2 Stations select the same station is

$$n\frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{n}$$

thus the probability that the two stations select a different frequency is the complementary:

$$1-\frac{1}{n}$$